# Show second Submit button after clicking first Submit with form submit - Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I've build a function in javascript to show me a second submit but only after the first submit was clicked.

Edited - this is ex.php:

```
<form method="post" action = "ex.php">
    <input type="submit" id="button" name="search" value="Search" 
    onclick="myFunction();" >
    <br>
     <input type="submit" name="search_close"  id="submit"  style="display: 
     none;" value="Find close results">
    </form>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
       echo "first search";
    }
     else if(isset($_POST['search_close']))
    {
       echo "second search";
    }
    else {
       echo "nothing";
    }
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    inputSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");     
    function myFunction(){
       inputSubmit.style.display = "block";    };
    </script>
```

Updated: 
I've edited in order to conclude the main problem.

So what I want is this:

a) The user has pressed the first submit button "search" then it will echo on the page "first search" and then show the second submit button "search_close" .

b)Then, if the user has pressed the second submit button it will show "second search".

```
When first Refreshing:
======
search (button)
======

if clicking the "search" button:
======
search (button)
======
first search  (text)
==================
Find close results (button)
==================

if clicking the "find close results:
======
search (button)
======
first search  (text)
==================
Find close results (button)
==================
second search  (text)
```

This code doesn't do what I want. Why?

Updated - why the button find close results disappers after one second?

```
<?php
session_start();
$db=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","travelersdb");

if(@$_SESSION["username"]){
    ?>
<?php
// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","travelersdb");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query) or die(mysqli_error($connect));
    return $filter_Result;
}

$submit_value = 0;
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{

    $Destination = $_POST['Destination'];
    $TypeOfTravel = $_POST['TypeOfTravel'];
    $Age= $_POST['Age'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $topic_name =  $_POST['topic_name'];
    $StartingPoint =  $_POST['StartingPoint'];


// search in all table columns
$query = "SELECT * FROM `topics`
              left join `users` on users.username = topics.topic_creator
              WHERE 1=1 "; 
if(!empty($Destination)) {
$query.="AND destination='$Destination'";
}
if(!empty($TypeOfTravel)) {
$query.=" AND typeTravel='$TypeOfTravel'";
}
if(!empty($Age)) {
$query.="AND age='$Age'";
}
if(!empty($email)) {
$query.=" AND email='$email'";
}
if(!empty($topic_name)) {
$query.=" AND topic_name='$topic_name'";
}
if(!empty($StartingPoint)) {
$query.=" AND StartingPoint='$StartingPoint'";
}

$search_result = filterTable($query);
$submit_value = 1; 
}

///Make The search more wider, only for the fields that were in the post
 else if(isset($_POST['search_close']))
{
    $Destination = $_POST['Destination'];
    $TypeOfTravel = $_POST['TypeOfTravel'];
    $topic_name =  $_POST['topic_name'];
    $StartingPoint =  $_POST['StartingPoint'];


// search in all table columns
$query = "SELECT * FROM `topics`
              left join `users` on users.username = topics.topic_creator
              WHERE 1=1 "; 
if(!empty($Destination)) {
$query.="AND destination='$Destination'";
}
if(!empty($TypeOfTravel)) {
$query.=" AND typeTravel='$TypeOfTravel'";
}
if(!empty($topic_name)) {
$query.=" AND topic_name='$topic_name'";
}
if(!empty($StartingPoint)) {
$query.=" AND StartingPoint='$StartingPoint'";
}
$search_result = filterTable($query); 
$submit_value = 2;
}
else {
   $query = "SELECT * FROM `topics`";
   $search_result = filterTable($query);
}
?>

<html>
    <head>

<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); ?>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

        <title>Home Page</title>  
         <style>
            .hidden {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function showHide()
            {
               var checkbox = document.getElementById("chk");
               var hiddeninputs = document.getElementsByClassName("hidden");
               for (var i=0; i != hiddeninputs.length; i++) {
                   if(checkbox.checked){
                       hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "block";
                   } else {
                       hiddeninputs[i].style.display = "none";
                   }
               }
           }

<?php 
if($submit_value == 1 || $submit_value == 2){ ?>
    myFunction();
   inputSubmit = document.getElementById("submit");     
   function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "block";   
    };
   <?php } ?>


        </script>
    <body>

    </body>
    </head>
    <?php include("header.php");?>
    <center>
        </br>
        <a href ="post.php"><button>Post</button></a>
        </br>
        <br/>
        <h4>Simple Serach</h4>



        <form action="" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="Destination" placeholder="Destination" value=
"<?php if(isset($_POST['Destination']))
{echo htmlentities($_POST['Destination']);}?>" ></br>
            <input type="text" name="TypeOfTravel" placeholder="Type Of Travel"
              value=
"<?php if(isset($_POST['TypeOfTravel']))
{echo htmlentities($_POST['TypeOfTravel']);}?>"
                   ></br>
            <input type="text" name="Age" placeholder="Age" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TypeOfTravel']))
{echo htmlentities($_POST['Age']);}?>">
       </br>
       </br>
    <!-- Advanced Search-->
       <input type="checkbox" name="chkbox" id="chk" onclick="showHide()" />


       <label for="chk"><b>Advanced search</b></label>
       </br>
       <input type ="text" name="email"  placeholder="Email"  class="hidden" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TypeOfTravel']))
{echo htmlentities($_POST['email']);}?>">
       <input type ="text" name="topic_name"  placeholder="topic name" class="hidden"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TypeOfTravel']))
{echo htmlentities($_POST['topic_name']);}?>">
       <input type="text" name="StartingPoint" placeholder="Starting Point"  class="hidden"value="<?php if(isset($_POST['TypeOfTravel']))
{echo htmlentities($_POST['StartingPoint']);}?>">
       </br><br/>

  <input type="submit" id="button" name="search" value="Search" 
onclick="myFunction();" >
  <br><br>
 <input type="submit" name="search_close"  id="submit"  style="display: 
 none;" value="Find close results">
        </form>    
        <br/>
        <?php echo '<table border="1px">';?>
                <td width="400px;" style="text-align:center;">
                 Name
                </td>
                  <td width="400px;" style="text-align:center;">
                Destination
                </td>
                 <td width="400px;" style="text-align:center;">
               Type Of Travel:
                </td>
                <td width="80px;" style="text-align: center;">
                  First Name
                </td>
                <td width="80px;" style="text-align: center;">
                  Age
                </td>
                 <td width="400px;" style="text-align:center;">
                 profile picture
                </td>
                <td width="80px;" style="text-align: center;">
                  Creator
                </td>
                <td width="80px;" style="text-align: center;">
                  Date
                </td>
      </tr>   
    </center>
<?php
$sql = "Select * from `topics`";
$check =  mysqli_query($db,$sql); 
$rows = mysqli_num_rows($search_result);
if($rows != 0){
     while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($search_result)){
         $id = $row['topic_id'];
         echo "<tr>";
         //echo "<td>".$row['topic_id']."</td>";
         echo "<td style='text-align:center;'><a href='topic.php?id=$id'>".$row['topic_name']."</a></td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['Destination']."</td>";
         echo "<td>".$row['typeTravel']."</td>";

         $sql_u = "Select * from users where username='".$row['topic_creator']."'";
         $check_u =  mysqli_query($db,$sql_u);
          while ($row_u = mysqli_fetch_assoc($check_u))
                          {
                           $user_id = $row_u['id'];
                           $profile_pic = $row_u['profile_pic'];
                           $firstname = $row_u['firstname'];
                           $age = $row_u['age'];
                            echo "<td>".$firstname."</td>";
                            echo "<td>".$age."</td>";
                            echo "<td><img src='".$profile_pic."' width='10%' height='10%' alt='me'></td>"; 
                            echo "<td><a href='profile.php?id=$user_id'>".$row['topic_creator']."</a></td>";
                          }
          $get_date = $row['date'];
         echo "<td>".$row['date']."</td>";             
         echo "</tr>";
     }
}else {
        echo "No topics found";
      }
echo "</table>";


if (@$_GET['action']=="logout")
{
    session_destroy();
    header('location:login.php');
}
}else 
    {
    echo "You must be logged in.";
    echo "<a href ='login.php'>Click here to login</a>";
    }
    ?>
</br>
</br>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does "doesn't seem to work" mean? Are you getting an error? What happens?

Comment: As an aside, you've got some HTML errors (`<center>` has been a deprecated tag for many years - use CSS to format and `</br>` is an invalid tag as `<br>` elements don't get closed. Also, you should not have two submit buttons unless you are submitting to two different locations. In your case, the first button should just be a `<button>`, not a submit button.

Comment: it doesn't show me the second submit button with the value="Find close results" :

Comment: @ScottMarcus, is this will solve the problem? because in the example it works with two submit buttons.

Comment: An `input type=submit` will automatically submit the form data upon clicking it. If your first button isn't supposed to do that and it is only supposed to reveal the actual submit button, then the first button should not be a submit button. When you say "It works", I think you are just referring to the second button appearing. The form itself won't work properly.

Comment: No - the first submit button should submit the form data to perform the first search query + show the second submit button and the second submit button should perform the second - there are two diffrent queries.

Comment: I don't think you are going to get too many answers here because your code is really a mess and includes many formatting problems that makes it difficult to sift through. Place opening curly braces on the same line with the structure they open. For example: `function () {` and `If() {`. Remove extraneous line feeds. Fix your HTML (problems mentioned earlier), remove inline CSS styles and inline JavaScript event attributes (`onclick`, etc.). All these things make your code difficult to read and can change the way the code processes.

Comment: It might be more informative to view the page source and look at just the HTML which is actually output, separate from the PHP code. Plus what everyone said.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, I did what you've asked me to do. I will be greatful for your help for required corrections for the updated post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set type button cause when you set type submit then form automatically submit so show second not show but it work.

```
<form method="post" action = "">
<input type="submit" id="button" name="search" value="Search" >
<br>
 <input type="submit" name="search_close"  id="submit"  style="display: 
 none;" value="Find close results">
</form>

<?php 
$submit_value = 0;
if(isset($_POST['search']))
{
   echo "first search";
   $submit_value = 1;

}
 else if(isset($_POST['search_close']))
{
   echo "first search";
   echo '<br>';
   echo "second search";
   $submit_value = 2;
}
else {
   echo "nothing";
}


?>

<script type="text/javascript">
<?php 
if($submit_value == 1 || $submit_value == 2){ ?>
    document.getElementById('submit').style.display = "block";   
   <?php } ?>
</script>
```

check this code

Comment: your code is better but I will clarify more in my post what needs to be the desired output.

Comment: check my update answer, if ok then next step i will do

Comment: check now, i think it will ok for you

Comment: thank you by almost. the "find close results" should show up until the search button was clicked.

Comment: what do you mean should show up? when page load then find close results not show?

Comment: can you check now?

Comment: Thank you. I seems to work but what is the reason for the "find close results" to disappear after a few seconds when I pressed the search button (the first one).

Comment: do you check now?

Comment: It works great on the example. In my wider code it just show up for one second and in need to catch the moment in order to press the "show close results" button :( do you have any idea why? I've posted my large code.

Comment: when form submit in this case need to time to submit form so in this case need time. if it is work then can you give me vote?

Comment: I didn't understand your last answer. coulde you take a look at the large code?  I want to except your answer, just think something is missing. Thank you!

Comment: Ok checking it. Wait

Comment: I think I have fixed it. The < form> spot was needed to be changed. Thank you for help. Answer accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I have cleaned up your code, but the issue of having two submit buttons still persists. Even if the clicking of the first button causes the second to show, the first button will cause the page to reload with the results from the form's `action` resource.  In this example, I have cancelled the form's submit event to show that the display of the second button works.

In the end, I think you are going about this all wrong. I think you should be making AJAX calls to your server-side resource and injecting the results of that call into your page - - no forms and no submits.

```js
// Don't forget to add "var" to your variable declarations, otherwise the variables
// become global!
var sub1 = document.getElementById("btnSub1"); 
var sub2 = document.getElementById("btnSub2"); 

// Set up the event handler for the first button
sub1.addEventListener("click", myFunction);

function myFunction(e){
  // Adjust classes, not individual styles
  sub2.classList.remove("hidden");
  
  // Cancel the native event and stop bubbling
  e.preventDefault();
  e.stopPropagation();
};
```

```css
.hidden { display:none; }
```

```html
<form>
  <!-- Submit buttons don't get a name attriute unless you expect their value to be submitted
       along with all the other form data. Inline styles should be avoided and internal style
       sheets used instead. And, inline JavaScript event attributes (onclick, etc.) should not
       be used. -->
  <input type="submit" id="btnSub1" name="search" value="Search" >
  <br>
  <input type="submit" id="btnSub2" class="hidden" value="Find close results">
</form>

    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['search']))
    {
       echo "first search";
    }
     else if(isset($_POST['search_close']))
    {
       echo "second search";
    }
    else {
       echo "nothing";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: have you ran the code to see? It doesn't show what I have drafted on to my edit post. It show me the buttons together on the first time.

Comment: @Toto88 I know. What I'm trying to show you is the proper way to code HTML, CSS and JavaScript. I explained why I'm having my code do what it does in the comments and I've also explained that I thing you are going about this entire process incorrectly.